# implementaion of remez exchange algorithm for filter design

Tags: c++, algorithm, matlab, filter, signal-processing

I have found C implementation for remez exchange algorithm(https://github.com/janovetz/remez-exchange/blob/master/remez.c) and I want to use this to implement a generic prototype lowpass filter. Although the comments have been provided to guide on how to use it I am having trouble implementing it. Could anyone tell me what are the correct inputs which I am suppose to give to the remez() function to get coefficients for lowpass filter because I suspect I am not providing the correct inputs.

Some information regarding what I am trying to do: I have been reading and experimenting with the code and I found out that for lowpass filter I should give type as 1(i.e Bandpass). Anyhow just to try the code I gave the parameters for bandpass filter in MATLAB and same parameters to remez() but the results are very different. Could somebody have a look at my coefficients and tell me what I am doing wrong because I don't get it?

**MATLAB:**

```
% All frequency values are in Hz.
Fs = 2000;  % Sampling Frequency
Fstop1 = 200;              % First Stopband Frequency
Fpass1 = 300;              % First Passband Frequency
Fpass2 = 700;              % Second Passband Frequency
Fstop2 = 800;              % Second Stopband Frequency
Dstop1 = 0.000177827941;   % First Stopband Attenuation
Dpass  = 0.0057563991496;  % Passband Ripple
Dstop2 = 0.000177827941;   % Second Stopband Attenuation
dens   = 20;               % Density Factor
% Calculate the order from the parameters using FIRPMORD.
[N, Fo, Ao, W] = firpmord([Fstop1 Fpass1 Fpass2 Fstop2]/(Fs/2), [0 1 ...
                           0], [Dstop1 Dpass Dstop2]);
```

These values (N, Fo, Ao, W) obtained from MATLAB, I feed to remez() function.

**So the C++ function looks like:** (just the part where I am calling the remez function)

```
int numtaps = 64;
int numbands = 3;
std::vector<double> h(numtaps);
double  bands[] = [0, 0.2000, 0.3000, 0.7000, 0.8000, 1.000];
double  des[] = [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0];
double weight[] = [0.000177827941, 0.0057563991496, 0.000177827941];
int type = 1;
int griddensity = 20;
remez(&(h[0]), int *numtaps, int *numband, const double bands[], const double des[], const double weight[], int *type, int *griddensity);
```

Could anyone please tell me how to use this code properly. I have not been able to find anything online about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Matlab's `firpm` and `firpmord` use band edge frequencies normalized by the Nyquist rate, such that the specified frequencies fall in the `[0,1]` range.
The [`remez`](https://github.com/janovetz/remez-exchange/blob/master/remez.c) function implementation you used on the other hand assumes that band edge frequencies are normalized by the sampling rate, such these frequencies fall in the `[0,0.5]` range. As a result you should divide each specified frequency by 2:

```
double  bands[] = [0, 0.2000/2, 0.3000/2, 0.7000/2, 0.8000/2, 1.000/2];
```

Also, to have smaller ripples in a given band you must increase the weight associated with that band, so to get the correct relative ripple amplitudes you should provide weights which are inversely proportional to the ripples:

```
double weight[] = {1.0/0.000177827941, 1.0/0.0057563991496, 1.0/0.000177827941};
```

You should then be able to call `remez` as follow:

```
remez(&(h[0]), &numtaps, &numbands, bands, des, weight, &type, &griddensity);
```

This should provide you a reasonable approximation of the specified bandpass filter. Note that since the desired filter characteristics are provided in the frequency-domain, you should be comparing the frequency responses of the designed filter rather than the filter coefficients `h` (which are in the time-domain). You could [`freqz`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/freqz.html) for this purpose. To actually meet the filter specification, you will probably have to increase `N` from the estimated `N=64` given by `firpmord` to around 68.

Finally, since you mentioned that your goal is to obtain a lowpass filter, you would achieve this by specifying a bandpass filter with 2 bands, with the first band having a desired value of 1 and the second a desired value of 0, in a way similar to the following:

```
int numbands = 2;
double  bands[] = [0, 0.2000/2, 0.3000/2, 0.5];
double  des[]   = [1, 1, 0, 0];
...
```

Comment: This was so so helpful. Thanks a lot for explaining. I was importing the filter coefficients into MATLAB and doing fft and plotting it to check the filter response but i was getting nowhere with it. And you are right about the filter order too. 68 gives much "smoother" ripples in the passband.

Comment: I was giving band edge frequency same as MATLAB(i.e normalized by nyquist rate) because that's what's been mentioned in code. Line 764 of the code which is here(https://github.com/janovetz/remez-exchange/blob/master/remez.c). Could you tell me how did you know that band edge frequencies need to be normalized by sampling frequency?

Comment: [Line 764](https://github.com/janovetz/remez-exchange/blob/master/remez.c#L764) is part of the Octave interface adaptation. Octave interface is made to be compatible with Matlab as much as possible, so the octave inputs are normalized by Nyquist rate and later on [line 798](https://github.com/janovetz/remez-exchange/blob/master/remez.c#L798) the frequencies are recomputed by dividing by 2 before being passed on to the actual C `remez` function.